# Nuxt site to serve multiple sites

Tags: nuxt.js

I have an API which serves data for multiple different websites - the different data is available to each site via an API key which must be included in every request.

Now, I want to create a Nuxt frontend for every site which uses that site's API key to get the correct data for that site.

So we'll end up with:-

Site A (uses API key "key-a") -> displays a website called "Site A"

Site B (uses API key "key-b") -> displays a website called "Site B"
etc.

But I want all the sites to share the same design - so they'll use all the same components, pages etc. - they'll just have different data on each one.

Is that possible and, if so, how would I do it? I know how to use environment variables in Nuxt but not sure how to split things up on a per-site basis.

Comment: There's a few ways to go about this, which is _best_ kinda depends on your setup. Like, if you are using SSR you would leverage Nuxt lifecycle hooks like asyncData and nuxtServerInit to fetch the correct data before pages are rendered on the server side. If it's a static site, then fetching the data in component lifecycle hooks like 'mounted' etc would be the way to go. Can you give a little more information?

Comment: They are SSR sites - and I know how to use asyncData to get the right data on the server side. My problem is that I don't know how to get the axios calls in the asyncData methods to use different API keys (for example) depending on the site that's running.

Comment: I'm guessing that I need to run several instances of the nuxt app, each with a different configuration file which dictates the API key to be used but I'm not sure how that would look.

Comment: Ok, just deleted my last comment as I think I mistook what you were after. Give me a minute.

Comment: Are you set on using keys for this? Totally possible, it's just you would have to run multiple instances of the Nuxt app and specify the config/env file as you mentioned. That's how I'm running a similar setup at the moment, using different build/start scripts for each site such as ```nuxt build --config-file src/some/path/nuxt.config.js --dotenv src/some/path/.env```. As an easier alternative, could your API check the origin coming in from the frontend request, and use that to determine which data to serve?

Comment: Ah, interesting - I must admit, I did wonder whether that would be possible. But I figured it might be easier with separate config files and startup scripts. I guess that, in an ideal world, I could run a single front end and it would read the origin host, use that to look up things like API keys, site names etc. and go from there. I've no idea how to do that though!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246649/discussion-between-nick-dawes-and-bodger).